# Can function parameter use an array method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, components, es6-promise

Preface: I'm still getting used to ES6 and working on my first React App via an online class. I'll share my issue here and my git repository for anyone who's willing to dig into it. The app allows you to search and organize books in different categories.

The error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
>
> at Object.mergeShelfAndSearch (BookUtils.js:22)
> at Search.js:41

`BookUtils.js` exports a couple of functions to React components (not sure how it knows where to go, but it works). The `Search.js` component handles the search functionality. While testing I'll search for something that doesn't exist(i.e 'zzzzz'). When I type something that I know exists I get the error above.

Code in `BookUtils.js` :

```
export const mergeShelfAndSearch = (shelf, search) => {
    
    const hashTable = {};
    
    shelf.forEach(book => hashTable[book.id] = book.shelf);

    search.forEach(book => {
        book.shelf = hashTable[book.id] || 'none';
       
    });

    return search;
}
```

The error being the 'shelf.forEach'.

Code in Search.js :

```
 updateSearch = () => {
        if (this.state.query === "") {
            this.setState({ error: false, books: [] });
            return;

        }

        BooksAPI.search(this.state.query).then(response => {

            let newList = [];
            let newError = false;
            

            if (response === undefined || (response.error && response.error !== "empty query")) {
                newError = true;
            } else if (response.length) {
                newList = BookUtils.mergeShelfAndSearch(this.props.selectedBooks, response);
               
                newList = BookUtils.sortAllBooks(newList);
               
            }
            this.setState({ error: newError, books: newList });
        })
    }
```

Error is in the else if statement with ''mergeShelfAndSearch' from `BookUtils.js`. I've tried setting 'shelf' as a global var and still get errors and I feel like I've put console.log(shelf); everywhere without any luck. Below is a link to my repo if any one is curios enough.  Thanks!

https://github.com/alecb513/reactnd-project-myreads-starter-master

Comment: that error would imply `this.props.selectedBooks` is undefined - basic debugging using console.log would confirm this - i.e. `console.log(this.props.selectedBooks)` before calling `BookUtils.mergeShelfAndSearch` is what I would do

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you kindly for your quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  else if (response.length) {
            newList = BookUtils.mergeShelfAndSearch(this.props.selectedBooks, response);

            newList = BookUtils.sortAllBooks(newList);

        }
```

To

```
  else if (response.length) {
            newList = BookUtils.mergeShelfAndSearch(Array.isArray(this.props.selectedBooks) ? this.props.selectedBooks: [], response);

            newList = BookUtils.sortAllBooks(newList);

        }
```

Or

```
  else if (response.length && Array.isArray(this.props.selectedBooks)) {
            newList = BookUtils.mergeShelfAndSearch(Array.isArray( this.props.selectedBooks, response);

            newList = BookUtils.sortAllBooks(newList);
```

The reason you get .forEach is undefined because initially this.props.selectedBooks might be undefined or null or an object. So doing .forEach on it will throw you an error. So to fix the issue check if it is an array or not and before passing this.props.selectedBooks to mergeShelfAndSearch function. Also make sure you send array of data to selectedBooks from parent component

Comment: If I could up vote this 100+ times I would!!!!! I've been stuck on this for 3 days and have plenty of more work to do before a deadline in a couple of weeks.  From what I can tell you solution is working every test.  Thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: You are welcome. We all make silly mistakes but spending 3 days on this small issue is too much. You can debug this with just one console log in mergeShelfAndSearch function to see what are the values you get when you do console.log(shelf); so you can easily do conditional check to avoid such issues. You will learn more. Keep learning.

Comment: Your right.  I have a tight deadline to finish this project (as well as others) for classes I'm taking.  I made the mistake of thinking 'following a tutorial' would 'speed things up.' But I've found I'm not understanding the code the way I would if I had just got in there and got my hands dirty - lesson learned!